# Why is my range function printing untruncated floats?

Tags: python

I made this range function so I could have something other than an integer step, and it works, but I am wondering why the floats are not truncated.

```
def drange(start, step):
    values = []
    r = start
    while r >= 0:
        values.append(r)
        r += step
    return values


print drange(2, -0.2)
```

Upon debugging I find that instead of this printing

```
[2, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0]
```

it instead prints

```
[2, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4000000000000001, 1.2000000000000002, 1.0000000000000002, 0.8000
000000000003, 0.6000000000000003, 0.4000000000000003, 0.2000000000000003, 2.7755
575615628914e-16]
```

Lol, no wonder my module isn't working. Why does this happen and how might I fix it?

Comment: The decimal module allows you to set precision. Have a look at: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Comment: Your range function can be broken by passing it a positive, rather than a negative `step`. You should _probably_ include a `stop` parameter, or just make it raise an error when a positive value is passed.

Comment: You might want to look at Numpy's `arange` and `linspace` functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is correct behavior, since one cannot express `0.2 = 1/5` in base 2, just like there is no way to express `1/3` in base 10.

Use [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) instead if you want to calculate in base 10.

Additionally, you should really use a generator, as in

```
def drange(start, step):
    r = start
    while r >= 0:
        yield r
        r += step
print list(drange(2, -0.2))
```

That allows users of `drange` to iterate over the values without memory being allocated for the whole list.